# Install chrome extension (crx) on Chrome 53.0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Chrome 53.0 on closed network (disconnected from the internet).
I need to install few chrome extensions, but I am getting the message:

> “can only be added from the Chrome Web Store.”

Using Windows 8.

What I have already tried:

1. add the –enable-easy-off-store-extension-install flag to chrome.exe
2. Unpack crx and load the folder from develop mode

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
The problem with Unpack the crx and load the folder was the  `__meta` directory

1. Unzip the crx file into a new directory
2. Remove _metadata directory if exist
3. Goto chrome://extensions/ Check on Developer mode
4. Select "Load unpacked extension" and select your extension folder